Prevent Google from applying email filters when uploading mail
I have an application that imports email messages into Gmail using this API:
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/GoogleId/messages

When I do this, Gmail applies previously created filters that operate on the message. This can be a good thing but in my application, I would prefer that it not do that.  Is there a way to disable that behavior?

Use the GMAIL API Insert method

Directly inserts a message into only this user's mailbox similar to
IMAP APPEND, bypassing most scanning and classification. Does not send
a message.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/insert

I believe the "insert" method is already what I'm doing - the only difference I see in the API is the prefix "gmail" instead of "www".  I did try changing it to "gmail" but I saw no difference in behavior.  I have a filter that searches for the subject of my test message, and if a match, adds the label "Bad".  This still happened after I ran my code.
